# I want the correct xpath for span and class

Tags: javascript, xpath

I want to find `RetailDischarge` xpath for `span` and `class` from the following html:

RetailDischarge

My script is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@class='menu-item-title']/span[text()='RetailDischarge']")).click();
```

I got the error message:

> invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath
>   expression

Comment: Please be specific. We do not know what exactly is Retail Discharge since it might be your personal application. If it is unable to find the location try with relative xpath.

Comment: i want to click the "RetailDischarge" menu which is in a span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This surely will work-

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'RetailDischarge')]"));`

Comment: extra space in ' RetailDischarge'

Comment: Saad, it is not working. Here is my Html, where i need to click the link "RetailDischarge". <span class="menu-item-title-wrap" data-click=".">
<span class="menu-item-title" data-click="..">RetailDischarge</span></span>

Comment: What is the error..??.. Might be loading problem. Have you provided wait..??

Comment: Enjoy. Please correct answer, so that the thread can be in solved mode